# Is there anything fundamentally wrong with 'autogenous expander cycle`?

Tags: engines, engine-design, design-alternative

This question is a spinoff from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41165/why-arent-expander-cycle-engines-used-on-lower-stages).

To set the context, here is my understanding of the expander cycle:

1. Closed expander cycle is very efficient, perhaps more efficient than staged combustion cycle. It also has very little mechanical complexity as compared to other cycles (look at the simplicity of [BE-7](https://www.blueorigin.com/engines/be-7)) which makes it very reliable (look at the longevity of [RL-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL10)). But closed expander cycle doesn't scale well, and engines with thrust over 150 kN are not practical.
2. Open expander cycle does not have the same scale limitations ([BE-3U](https://www.blueorigin.com/engines/be-3) has 710 kN of thrust, and [LE-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LE-9) is expected to have close to 1,500 kN of thrust). But it is less efficient because a small portion of the propellant is ejected unburnt. This puts it closer to gas-generator cycle engines in terms of efficiency.

So, why not route the exhaust of the turbine of the open expander cycle back to the tanks to pressurize them autogenously (see diagram and description below)? This should combine the best of both worlds: efficiency of the closed expander cycle with power of the open expander cycle. But, as far as I know, this hasn't been done yet - so, maybe I'm missing something?

#### Brief description

The cycle works pretty much in the same way as the open dual expander cycle - but instead of discarding the output of the turbopumps, the propellant is returned to its respective tanks.

As far as I understand, only about 2% of the propellant needs to be diverted to run the pumps. But I have only a single source for this (page 5 from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303181821/http://www.la.dlr.de/ra/sart/publications/pdf/2003-4597.pdf)). So, if anyone has better numbers on how much of the propellant is usually used to run the pumps in an open expander cycle - would really appreciate the info.

As the propellant returns back to the tanks, most of it condenses back into a liquid form as it comes in contact with the subcoold propellant remaining in the tanks (I understand that this is what happens in plain autogenous pressurization as well). Different methods of injecting the propellant back into the tanks can be used to control the rate of condensation.

The temperature of the propellant returned to the tanks is around 400K (this also comes from the same page 5 from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303181821/http://www.la.dlr.de/ra/sart/publications/pdf/2003-4597.pdf) - so, any validation or invalidation of this would be helpful). And since only about 2% of the propellant is returned, it's not enough to significantly heat up the rest of the propellant in the tanks.

The last point is true only while there is a lot of propellant still left in the tanks - but won't be true once the tanks are almost empty. At this point, the exhaust of the turbopumps would need to be largely discarded - as in the regular open expander cycle.

[image]

Comment: you lose the advantages of sub-cooling your propellant if you start heating it. Calculate the heat you're throwing into the tank - SHC of gaseous range, latent heat of evaporation, SHC of liquid range, compare to SHC of subcooled propellant (SHC tends to reduce as temperature gets lower)

Comment: look at the volume of gas you're pumping into the tanks, how do you ensure that's all condensed before it gets vented from the tank. see if you can find flow rates for autogenous pressurisation systems, and compare to the flow rate of your expander.

Comment: @JCRM - I think autogenous pressurization systems are designed to minimize condensation - so, their flow rates are probably not super informative. It seems to me that condensation rate is not a fundamental challenge. Heat capacity for fuel is probably not a fundamental challenge as well. In the worst case, propane can be used which has a huge spread between melting and boiling points (about 140 degrees) and has a fairly stable [SHC](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-capacity-propane-Cp-Cv-isobaric-isochoric-d_2060.html) across different temperatures.

Comment: Heat capacity of oxygen might be a problem though, because the spread between melting and boiling point is only 30 degrees. So, this probably requires more precises analyses.

Comment: The flow rates are informative, because they show you how much heat is needed. My back of the envelope calculations show you can handle about 0.5% from 400k before your subcooled methane starts to boil

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how you expect to condense it so quickly. I think going closed cycle would be far easier.

Comment: @JCRM - yeah, I'm starting to think that methane may not be the best fuel for this system. But I think other fuels (e.g. propane) might work? As for condensation, to be honest, I haven't given it a lot of thought - but one approach might be to release the gas below the surface of the liquid and let it cool as it bubbles up to the top.

Comment: So, doing back of the envelope calculations for propane, the numbers look very favorable. Assuming the gas returns at 400K, nearly 30% of the mass would need to be pumped back into the tank before subcooled propane starts to boil. This is much less than 2% - so, there is a big "safety" margin. For oxygen, things are somewhat less clear: similar type of calculations show that only about 10% would be needed to start boiling oxygen in the tank (if I did my calculations correctly). So, the "safety margin" is much less.

Comment: OK, now, how is the change in temperature of the propane going to affect the density? how much efficiency will you lose by your propellant mix being "off" as a result?

Comment: Injecting 2% of propane mass at 400K back into the tank with liquid propane stored at 90K should change the temperature of the propellant in the tank buy less than 10K (this is of course is an oversimplification, but should be roughly in the right ballpark). So, it will go from 90K to 100K, and the density will change by about 3%. Not sure if this will have any significant effect on mix, especially since density of oxygen will be changing at the same time as well.

Comment: @JCRM - btw, how did you get methane boiling at 0.5% of mass injected? I'm getting that it would need to be around 5% of mass injected at 400K to start boiling the tank.

Comment: It looks like I applied a correction to the value to account for the difference between the SHC of Hydrogen (from your source) and Methane - the amount of work you get out of a turbine being (basically) the heat extracted from the flow

Comment: I then took the resulting ~4 times as much heat as needed to boil, and applied that to the 2% figure. Whereas I should have said you could only sink 5% of the hot gas, of the 20% needed.

Comment: There's not enough space to contain all the turbine exhaust gas. Liquid methane is 700x denser than gas, so for each 1 part volume of liquid methane burned you generate 700*2%=14x turbine exhaust gas in volume. If you really wanted, then your tank needs to withstand 14atm pressure to contain it. I don't think it's feasible either or both way (increasing tank strength or reduce gas exhaust).

Comment: The turbine exhaust is not injected into the tank all at the same time. It is injected gradually as the engine burns, and majority of the 2% liquefies due to condensation as it comes in contact with the liquid propellant in the tanks. So - I don't think tank space is going to be an issue.

Comment: you still have to explain how you manage to liquefy it so quickly

Comment: I'm not sure how to definitively answer this question. The mass flow back to the tanks is rather small. For example, if the mass flow from the tanks is 500 kg/s, mass flow back to the tanks is only 10 kg/s. It seems like condensing 10 kg/s shouldn't be too challenging. I mentioned one option in the comments above: pipe the exhaust to the bottom of the tanks and release it there. As the gas bubbles up to the top, it will naturally cool and liquefy. But I'm not sure how to estimate the depth needed for this to work (e.g. maybe the gas will liquefy after passing through 2m or through 20m).

Comment: 10kg of methane at 400k is about 20 cubic meters. - and you're still using 2% - for methane it'll be about 15%, so lets say you're injecting 100 cubic meters of gas into your tank every second. As each of the bubbles collapses, it's send a shock through the methane

Comment: 15% is because of the difference in SHC between methane and hydrogen - right? I assumed that it would be partially offset by needing a less powerful turbine as you don't need to move as much methane as hydrogen (in terms of volume) - but maybe I'm not thinking about it correctly? As for volume, in either case it would be somewhat less because you'd be injecting methane back into the tank at between 3 and 5 bar. So, even at 15% would be less than 50 cubic meters. And to mitigate this, you could inject it in multiple places - this way, the bubbles wouldn't be too big.

Comment: @JCRM - I updated the post with estimates of how much propellant would need to be pumped back based on the differences in SHC with hydrogen. Seems like methane indeed is a pretty bad option for this - but propane might still work.

Comment: Not an expert by any means but don't you need a pressure differential between the input and output of the pump to extract work. EG pushing the exhaust into the tank to pressurize it would reduce the power output of the pump vs venting it. Lower pump pressure then means your chamber pressure is lower and less efficient engine. I'd think you could try to compensate by increasing the percentage of expanded gas going through the pumps but the heat capacity of the LoX is already looking pretty marginal for this scheme.

Comment: @EvanSteinbrenner - I think putting the exhaust back into the tanks is almost as good as venting it. The tanks are usually at 3 - 5 bar, while the pressure at turbine input is over 120 bar. So, you lose 2% - 3% of power vs. venting it - but that's not too significant.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in the comments and on some additional research, I'll try to answer my own question:

The design, at least as is, does not seem to be workable.

First, while it takes only 2% of propellant mass to run the pumps when the working fluid is hydrogen, it will take much more than 2% for other fluids. Based on my rough calculations, it would take 10% - 12% of methane, and 8% - 10% of oxygen to run their respective pumps. One other potential fuel to use might be propane, but I got conflicting numbers trying to calculate how much propane would be needed to run the pumps.

Second, pumping around 10% of propellants back to the tanks will affect the temperature of the tanks significantly. In fact, in case of methane or hydrogen, it will actually vaporize the propellant in the tanks. For oxygen, it will get it very close to the boiling point (though, as long as you pump less than 12% back, oxygen shouldn't vaporize). For propane, it shouldn't be a problem since propane has a very high boiling point (231K) - but again, not sure how much propane needs to be pumped back for the scheme to work.

Lastly, and perhaps more importantly, in this design most of the heat energy extracted from the nozzle does no useful work. About 90% of the heated up propellant is burnt immediately. Thus, only about 10% of the energy is used to run the pumps. So, unless there is a lot of extra heat available, this design will not work. And if there is a lot of extra heat available, a closed expander cycle would probably work better.

Another potential issue brought up in the comments was that cooling the propellant once it returns to the tanks will be difficult. I don't believe that's a fundamental problem and can be addresses in a number of ways (e.g. releasing the gas close to the bottom of the tanks and let it cool as it bubbles up) - but I don't have a definitive proof for this.

To sum up: this design will not work with fuels like hydrogen and methane. It might work with propane but even then, probably would not be the most efficient way to use heat energy. This is probably why it hasn't been used anywhere.

Comment: Also, the back pressure from the tank will negatively impact the work of your turbine...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at a **split** dual expander cycle. In this case the propellants are passed through a pump in two stages/two consecutive pumps.

After the first stage, some of the propellent is sent to the combustion chamber and the remainder goes through the high pressure pump and then is sent to cool the chamber/nozzle and the heated propellent changes phase and drives the corresponding turbine. Maybe (part of) the propellent exiting the turbine can be used for autogeneous pressurization (after heat exchange with the fresh propellent, if necessary).